Update subset of insert variables
In my app, a user can either create a stage object or update one that already exists. I use the same form for filling out the information, having the data already in there if the stage already exists. Because of this, I would like to do an upsert into the database when the user saves the stage. My local database is with drift, so I could easily write an SQL query that inserts all the rows, but ignores columns like id and created_at when doing an update. Is it possible to do something similar with supabase? I would like to save the same created_at and updated_at timestamps both locally and remote, so on insert I would like to insert these values.
